# Opening Solution file in Cygwin / Bash

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to set up a simple bash alias that will open a solution file in the current directory via `cygstart`

I'm unsuccessfully trying something like

```
ls | grep '.sln' | cygstart $0
```

I'm no expert in bash commands and was wondering what the correct command is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to try:

```
ls *.sln | xargs cygstart
```

or better:

```
find . -iname "*.sln" -print | xargs cygstart
```